# VS 2015: Running Unit Tests from console, Selenium ChromeDriver problems

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, selenium-chromedriver, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm 100% new here, and I'm not sure if anything else is expected before I post this question. But I didn't find anything about this exact issue when searching, so here goes:

I have a Solution framework using Selenium ChromeDriver for automating a web site, and an included Unit Test project for running the tests.

The tests can be run fine from the VS Test Explorer. But when I try running them from the VS console with

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:d:\Source\Workspaces\QA\Automation\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll /resultsfile:d:\QA\testresults\autotests\regressiontests\tests.trx
```

i get these errors in the results file:

```
Test method Tests.BasicTests.Data.GetSiteData.GetMyElementId threw exception:
System.Exception: File not found
at Bytescout.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.LoadFromFile(String FileName, CacheType Cache, String Delimiter, Encoding Encoding, String Password)
at Bytescout.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.LoadFromFile(String FileName)
at TestData.Readers.ExcelByteScout.ExcelFindRows(String url, String sheetname, String value, Int32 col) in d:\Source\Workspaces\QA\FlowAutomation\TestData\Readers\EscelByteScout.cs:line 113
at TestData.SiteData.MyElements.GetElementId(String location, String element) in d:\Source\Workspaces\QA\Automation\TestData\SiteData\MyElements.cs:line 27
at Tests.BasicTests.Data.GetSiteData.GetMyElementId() in d:\Source\Workspaces\QA\Automation\Tests\BasicTests\Data\GetSiteData.cs:line 13
```

- This is complaining about a Project -> Class in the solution which reads test data (user logins, CSS elements...) from an excel file.

and

```
Initialization method Tests.TestTests.OpenTests.OpenMyLabDrop2.Init threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html..
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
at Common.Selenium.GCDriver.Initialize() in d:\Source\Workspaces\QA\FlowAutomation\Common\Selenium\GCDriver.cs:line 19
at FlowTests.Base.MyLabDrop2Test.Init() in d:\Source\Workspaces\QA\FlowAutomation\FlowTests\Base\MyLabDrop2Test.cs:line 15
```

- this complains about a missing ChromeDriver.exe which is definetely not missing.

I'm not COMPLETELY new to VS and Selenium, but this I don't get, since the tests run fine from VS but complain about missing references from the console.

So I'm pretty sure there's something I'm missing when running the tests from the console, but what?

EDIT:

The relevant code from ExceByteScout.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Bytescout.Spreadsheet;

namespace TestData.Readers {
    public class ExcelByteScout {
        public static List<string> ExcelReturnXYZ(string url, string sheetname, string cell1, string cell2, string cell3) {
        Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet();
        document.LoadFromFile(url);
        Worksheet worksheet = document.Workbook.Worksheets.ByName(sheetname);
        List<string> cellvalues = new List<string>();

        string name = worksheet.Cell(cell1).Value.ToString();
        string user = worksheet.Cell(cell2).Value.ToString();
        string pass = worksheet.Cell(cell3).Value.ToString();
        cellvalues.Add(name);
        cellvalues.Add(user);
        cellvalues.Add(pass);

        document.Close();

        return cellvalues;
    }

    public static string[] ExcelFindRows(string url, string sheetname, string value, int col) {
        Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet();
        Worksheet worksheet = null;
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        string[] userdata = null;

        try {
            document.LoadFromFile(url);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        try {
            worksheet = document.Workbook.Worksheets.ByName(sheetname);
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException nrex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(nrex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (!worksheet.Cell(i, col).ValueAsString.Equals("")) {
            if (worksheet.Cell(i, col).ValueAsString.Equals(value)) {
                int rowcellcount = 0;

                for (int y = 0; !worksheet.Cell(i, y).ValueAsString.Equals(""); y++) {
                    rowcellcount++;
                }

                userdata = new string[rowcellcount];
                for (int x = 0; x < rowcellcount; x++) {
                    userdata[x] = worksheet.Cell(i, x).ValueAsString;
                }

                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        document.Close();
        return userdata
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

The FileNotFound problem was due to a relative path.

But the ChromeDriver not found issue is a mystery. Specifically because this has worked before, in a different solution but with the exact same way of running the tests from the console.

Also, I'm standing in the /Debug folder of the project when I run MSTest.exe, and chromedriver.exe IS in this folder. I cannot see where else it needs to be?

Comment: Can you post you code in EscelByteScout.cs?

Comment: I can, but what will that help? The code works fine when running the test from test explorer.

Answer (score 1):

File not found usually means that the file is not found on the location you expect it to be. This can happen because you run from an other path or the file is not copied.

Check the url before the line document.LoadFromFile(url); by Console.WriteLine(url). Then copy the excel to the correct location or fix the url.

Comment: Hm. Setting the file to "Copy if newer" or "Copy allways" in VS doesn't help. Maybe the problem is that I'm using a relative URL in the code handling the data file?